# How to remove images from PDF?

Tags: python, image, pdf, digital-signature

I have a batch of pdfs that contain images of digital signatures (encircled in green).

What I want is to remove them or at least what is written on it but i couldnt find any solution, I've tried the following:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader,PdfWriter  
reader = PdfReader('C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Downloads\\JG_1_01221-2020-0-1801-JR-LA-06.pdf') 
writer = PdfWriter() 
for page in reader.pages: 
   writer.add_page(page) 
with open('C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\DEP\\Lats.pdf', "wb") as f:
   writer.write(f)
```

But it does not work, it fills the document with nonsense symbols and erase the words, like below ...

[image]

What can I use to remove them?

Comment: PyMuPDF lets you remove images that can be identified via their xref. It is a method of PyMuPDF's `Page` class. See example scripts [here](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/tree/master/examples/replace-image).

Comment: I don't know how to do this using Python but all you need to do is to make the signature field invisible (e.g. by setting its **Rect** to `[0 0 0 0]`. As this breaks the digital signature anyways, one can actually also simply remove the signature field (both from the **Annots** of its page and from the **AcroForm** dictionary).

Comment: @KJ *"I tried crudely to zero one rect probably wrong one or wrong state and it blew the whole file"* - That's funny. I tested my approach  (applying the change with a hex editor) and it worked alright. Because the OP has not provided a link to a chosen example file, though, we all tested with different ones. Yours might just have been more broken than mine. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use PyMuPDF, I think it is currently the most powerful python library for handling PDF.

```py
import fitz


def remove_images(input_pdf, output_pdf):
    doc = fitz.open(input_pdf)
    for page in doc:
        img_list = page.get_images()
        for img in img_list:
            page.delete_image(img[0])

    doc.save(output_pdf)


remove_images("input.pdf", "output.pdf")
```

Comment: I tried your code but delete_image results in an error. The message is: **'Document' object has no attribute 'is_image'**

Comment: Did you install Pymupdf correctly instead of fitz?

Comment: Yes i did. I check in a blog that someone else had the same problem and he said it was a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I tried removing signatures several ways but generally, either got the same as yourself (random low density of characters) OR totally lost the text to vectors OR got other poor returns. As soon as you distort those signatures everything else gets distorted:

[image]

**Except** if I import into Word, where the signatures are automatically removed!

[image]

### Edit

Based on @mkl's comment that I should have done better, I went back to the first file and tried tried again. Here we can see I have zer0d 2 images and about to zero 3rd, while monitoring results live on the right.

[image]

All 4 are now Zero and text is still selectable

[image]

But as expected the Signatures are now invalid

[image]

So best to roll back to rev1 before any other signing by remove chain (I used Acrobat Reader, Save As) as hinted by @mkl (requires a bit of fiddling like before but now it's easier to remove just one signature, and the signatures are all gone.)

[image]

Comment: Yea, so it does work. And now the op surely wants to know how to do that with python 

Comment: What did you use to convert PDFs into docx file? I used ILovePDF and Acrobat but those method failed because the signatures were still there. My main goal is to remove these signatures from each pdf in a batch of 1000 pdfs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

`cpdf -draft in.pdf -o out.pdf`

to remove all images. There is a `-draft-remove-only` option described in section 19.1 of the manual for finer control.

**[Edit]**
However from comments below

> **the solution is** `cpdf -remove-annotations in.pdf -o out.pdf`. Turns out these are annotations.

Comment: Ah, we have an actual file to look at. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the solution is `cpdf -remove-annotations in.pdf -o out.pdf`. Turns out these are annotations.

Comment: pardon my ignorance but what type of code is that ?

Comment: It's a command at the command line. If you're not familiar with how to use the command line on your computer, you'll have to learn that first, and then install `cpdf`, and then you'll be ready to go.